# How to make the output print only once

Tags: c++

I am making a number guessing game. The problem is: when the number is guessed correctly and the computer asks if the user wants to play again, it takes in the input and asks the same question again before either exiting the game or restarting it.

I've tried adjusting the shouldPlayAgain() function by adding

```
else if(input == 'N') 
   return false;
```

but I still get the same issue. Here is my code: *Note that the int main function must be like this. I cannot add changes to it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void playOneGame();
char getUserResponseToGuess(int);
int getMidpoint(int, int);
bool shouldPlayAgain();

int main()
{
    do
    {
        playOneGame();
    } while (shouldPlayAgain());

    return 0;
}

void playOneGame()
{
    int low = 1;
    int high = 100;
    int guess = getMidpoint(low, high);
    char response;

    cout << "Welcome! Please think of a number from 1 to 100.\n";
    response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);

    //Keeps guessing until it guesses the correct number
    while(response != 'C')
    {
        if(response == 'H')
        {
            low = guess+1;
            guess = getMidpoint(low, high);
            response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
        }
        else if(response == 'L')
        {
            high = guess-1;
            guess = getMidpoint(low, high);
            response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
        }
    }

    if(response == 'C')
    {
        shouldPlayAgain();
    }
}

char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)
{
        char HLC;
        cout << "Is the number " << guess << " ? (H/L/C)\n";
        cin >> HLC;
        return HLC;
}

int getMidpoint(int low, int high)
{
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    return mid;
}

bool shouldPlayAgain()
{
    char input;
    cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N)\n";
    cin >> input;

    if(input == 'Y')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

This is a sample output. I don't understand why it's printing the question twice before finally executing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Welcome! Please think of a number from 1 to 100.
Is the number 50 ? (H/L/C)
L
Is the number 25 ? (H/L/C)
H
Is the number 37 ? (H/L/C)
H
Is the number 43 ? (H/L/C)
L
Is the number 40 ? (H/L/C)
C
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
Y
Would you like to play again? (Y/N)
Y
Welcome! Please think of a number from 1 to 100.
Is the number 50 ? (H/L/C)
```

Comment: Because you call it explicitly when 'C' is typed. Remove that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call to `shouldPlayAgain()` from `playOneGame()`.

It's called in `main()` after each return from `playOneGame()`.